# What is the name of this Dragon Ball Z RPG?

Tags: product-identification

It used the Fuzion RPG system and featured rolling tons of dice to represent the massive amounts of power that DBZ characters typically possess.

Comment: Meta discussion: [Can we respond to a closed recommendation question by self-answering another question?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6598)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of this game is [Dragon Ball Z: The Anime Adventure Game](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/7601/dragon-ball-z) and was published in 1999 by R. Talsorian Games.